# I can't send post request in jquery

Tags: jquery, post

```
$.getJSON(get, function (data) {

        if(data.results[0])
        { ver = data.results[0];
            $("#result").html(ver);}
            else
        $("#result").html("This source does not provide the lyrics you want. Try Sources #1 and #2");

    });
    $.post("check.php", { 'vid': 'gS9o1FAszdk', 'sursa': "1", 'vers':ver } ,function(dt){alert(ver);});
```

This is my code and has no effects. If i delete the 'vers' from data ,the script works fine. What's wrong?

Answer (score 6):

because **AJAX is asynchronous**. So your `post` method will not wait for the `getJSON` to finish executing and use the value in `ver`. You should move the post call to the call back function of getJSON

```
$.getJSON(get, function (data) {
  var ver =""
  if(data.results[0])
        { ver = data.results[0];
            $("#result").html(ver);
        }
        else
        {  
           $("#result").html("This source does not provide the lyrics you want. Try Sources #1 and #2");
        }
       $.post("check.php", 
               { 'vid': 'gS9o1FAszdk', 'sursa': "1", 'vers':ver } ,function(dt){
                alert(ver);
       });

});
```